# Как в php определить поддержку htaccess?

Tags: .htaccess, php

Мы не знаем, под каким демоном запустились (вернее можем определить из php). Задача следующая: написан скрипт, который потом неизвестно где будет использоваться. Для его запуска удобно использовать ЧПУ. Но не беда, если ЧПУ не поддерживает сервер, скрипт может и так (просто ему нужно знать, что не поддерживает). Пока делается просто `define('HTACCESS_ON',TRUE|FALSE)`. Хочется избавится от лишней константы, если это возможно.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Файл .htaccess

```
SetEnv htaccess_allowed 1
PassEnv htaccess_allowed
```

Файл test.php

```
die(var_dump($_ENV['htaccess_allowed']));
```

Answer (score 2):

Предложу свой вариант решения проблемы.

Создаем папку test. Кидаем туда:

- index.html
- index.php
- .htaccess

В последний пишем стандартно: использовать php или html (тот, что не стандартен). В файлы index.x пишем 1 и 0. Инклюдим по URL папку и в зависимости от полученной цифры узнаем, работает или нет.

Походу вариант извратский и, я думаю, есть способ проще, но, мне кажется, этому варианту суждено было оказаться тут. )

Comment: Можно просто с test/index.html перенаправлять на test/index2.html, тогда и думать о дефолтной странице не надо.

Comment: Спасибо, Сергей. Скажите, пожалуйста, вы всегда используете такие методы программирования?) Сори, но не подходит такой вариант.

Comment: Нет не всегда.) Просто это первое, что пришло в голову.) Я полагаю, что есть функция для проверки, но, возможно, в некоторых случаях то, что я написал единственный вариант для проверки. Кстати, я так понимаю, что у вас как-то используется этот модуль? Можно узнать как, возможно, есть не прямой способ узнать об этом в том месте, где это нужно.

Comment: В общем-то предложу этот результат еще кэшировать и он вполне адекватен будет. 

`if (!file_exists('allowed.htaccess')) { проверяем(); } else $result=file_get_contents('allowed.htaccess');`

Comment: Где используется этот модуль: неизвестно: написан скрипт для новичков, которые максимально просто должны сделать сложные вещи. Для них надо просто скопировать скрипт и все. Я свел к минимуму настройку в виде констант. Данный скрипт может использовать htaccess. Хотелось бы установить флажок автоматом. А где скрипт будет стоять в конечном счете, я не знаю.